# Hospital Charges Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a visual basic project for school that calculates your total during a hospital stay. It works for the most part, but I'm supposed to be getting an error message when a negative number is being entered and I'm not getting that message. Here is the coding as I have it right now:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'close form
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'clear form
    txtLab.Clear()
    txtMedication.Clear()
    txtPhysical.Clear()
    txtStay.Clear()
    txtSurgical.Clear()
    txtStay.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'class level declaration
    Const DayRate As Decimal = 350D 'cost per day


    'declare variables
    Dim Physical As Decimal
    Dim Surgical As Decimal
    Dim Lab As Decimal
    Dim Medication As Decimal
    Dim Stay As Decimal
    Try
        'Copy the scores into the variables
        Stay = CDec(txtStay.Text) * DayRate
        Medication = CDec(txtMedication.Text)
        Surgical = CDec(txtSurgical.Text)
        Lab = CDec(txtLab.Text)
        Physical = CDec(txtPhysical.Text)
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter numeric values")
        Return

        'Find out if box enteries are negative or not
        If Convert.ToDecimal(Lab) < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
            Return
            txtLab.SelectAll()
        ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(Medication) < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
            Return
            txtMedication.SelectAll()
        ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(Surgical) < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
            Return
            txtSurgical.SelectAll()
        ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(Physical) < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
            Return
            txtPhysical.SelectAll()
        ElseIf Convert.ToDecimal(Stay) < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Negative Numbers", "Try Agian")
            Return
            txtStay.SelectAll()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
Function CalcStayCharges() As Decimal
    CalcStayCharges = (CDec(txtStay.Text) * 350)
End Function
Function CalcMiscCharges() As Decimal
    CalcMiscCharges = CDec(txtMedication.Text) + CDec(txtLab.Text) + CDec(txtPhysical.Text) + CDec(txtSurgical.Text)
End Function
Function CalctotalCharges() As Decimal
    CalctotalCharges = (CalcStayCharges() + CalcMiscCharges())
End Function

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'calculates total of stay
    Dim decTotal As Decimal

    decTotal = CalctotalCharges()

    lblTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VBA and VB.Net are two distinct languages even if they look alike. Please tag your questions with the proper tag so the right people will see it

Comment: The code that checks for negative numbers is in the Form's Load event handler; it will execute one time when the form is loaded and before the use types anything in the TextBoxes. You need to validate the contents of the TextBoxes at the time the Calculate Button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The code you have in the **Catch** clause doesn't execute because no exceptions occur.  You should move your **If.. Else..** statements before the **Catch** clause.